# WaveShare display (7 inch) doesn't respond to touch, after playing YouTube videos in Raspberry PI 4

Tags: display, touchscreen, raspberry-pi-os

I have an issue with my WaveShare display (7-inch LCD with case) where when I connect it to my Raspberry PI 4 and play youtube videos for some time in the chromium browser, the screen doesn't respond to touch. This issue only happens for some panel items like Volume, Network, Bluetooth, etc, but Menu, Command Line, and File Explorer work fine.

When I use VNC and click on those panel items, it works fine but only doesn't respond when touched on the screen manually.

I have to reboot my raspberry pi to restore the touch ability of the LCD screen.

Please help me resolve this issue permanently.

Comment: If you can, try to see if an error pops up. If you can , when the issue occurs, check the logs of the raspberry pi. Check if there is an error related to your issue, and please show it here.